# Attaching models to elements created in a custom directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am attempting to build an angular directive that creates a collage of elements. Inside my directive, I iterate through the list of images that i receive, and I have some logic to place them inside the container, which all works fine. IE:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs){
  scope[model]["images"].forEach(data){
    var image = angular.element(document.createElement("img"));

    /* build out the element */

    element.append(image);
  }
}
```

However, I would like to be able to define a click handler like you can with ng-repeat, where you can have something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div ng-click="action(item)'></div>
</div>
```

I'm assuming I need to do something like attach a scope to the elements I'm creating, and within that scope, I would assign a value to `item`? Would I do this by creating a separate directive?

Comment: Why are you creating your HTML manually. Why don't you simply use `ng-repeat` to iterate over `scope.model.images` inside the directive's template?

Comment: Well, it initially seemed easier to build out the html programatically since there were some things in the models that would affect the styling, such as heights, widths, and background images

Comment: Am I able to do both? Can I use ng-repeat inside the template to create the elements, then iterate over the elements and modify them based on their data models?

Comment: Form what I see, I think `ng-repeat` is your friend. If you find a problem using it, post another question. Anyway, you are not meant to manually access the DOM elements, when using angular, because there's almost always a different way (using built-in directives).